# Cxf Web service design qestion

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cxf

i've a design problem:

I'll describe the issue using an example:

```
@WebService
public interface GlossaryWebService {
   @Secured("READ")
   public void foo();

   @Secured("READ")
   public void goo(); 
}
```

Implementation:

```
@WebService
public class GlossaryWebServiceImpl implements GlossaryWebService{


   private GlossaryService glossaryService;

   @Override
   public void foo() {
      glossaryService.foo();
   }

   @Override
   public void goo() {
      glossaryService.goo();
   } 
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface GlossaryService {  
   public void foo();
   public void goo(); 
}
```

Implementation:

```
public Class GlossaryServiceImpl extends GlossaryService{

   @Override
   public void foo() {
       // impl
   }

   @Override
   public void goo() {
       // impl
   }
}
```

As you can see we've GlossaryWebServiceImpl implementing GlossaryWebService
and GlossaryServiceImpl implementing GlossaryService!

the issue is that the GlossaryWebServiceImpl acts as facade (for GlossaryService), and this 
cause code duplication. the methods in GlossaryService needs also to be in GlossaryWebService
and the methods in GlossaryServiceImpl needs also to be in GlossaryWebServiceImpl as well!

I can save the creation of GlossaryWebServiceImpl by making GlossaryServiceImpl to implement GlossaryWebService 
and by that we'll have only 2 iterfaces and one implementation!

but this also makes problem because i want that the `@Secured` annotation (on GlossaryWebService) 
to be performed only when going through the web service and not when calling to the methods on GlossaryServiceImpl!

If someone have any idea suggestion, it would be very helpful!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since GlossaryWebServiceImpl is your entry point when accessng your service form Web Service, I would put all the Web Service related settings (roles, othe annotations) in it and put all the   Business Logic in GlossaryServiceImpl:

```
@WebService
public class GlossaryWebService{


   private GlossaryService glossaryService;

   @Secured("READ")
   public void foo() {
      glossaryService.foo();
   }

   @Secured("READ")
   public void goo() {
      glossaryService.goo();
   } 
}
```